# How to Convert String to Time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert DateTime to Time. I successfully converted it to a String using DateFormat but now i want to convert this String to Time (H,M,S). Is there a way to directly parse and convert the variable?

Comment: Do you mean `TimeOfDay`?

Comment: No Time variable

Comment: There is no `Time` variable unless maybe you created yours

Comment: Why not extract the time from the `DateTime` directly?  Also, what is `Time`?

Comment: Yes i want to exactly extract time from date time

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer if you explained _why_ you needed a `Time` object specifically. What are you planning to _do_ with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Dart, there is no such thing as a `Time` object. In Flutter, though, you generally want to represent specific times (without a date component) with [`TimeOfDay`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay-class.html). Unfortunately, it doesn't have a `parse` method for parsing timestamp strings, so the easiest way to get it is by passing in the `DateTime` you started with:

```dart
TimeOfDay time = TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(myDateTime);
```

If you also require the seconds component, unfortunately `TimeOfDay` doesn't support that. In that case, you will either have to create your own `Time` class or just use the `DateTime` time components directly.